# How to send multiple post request with jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, post

I need to send a post request before previously post request return answer.

Here is an example.

```
<button name="button1" onclick="post1();" >post1</button>
<button name="button2" onclick="post2();" >post1</button>
```

And this is javascript codes

```
function post1(){
    $.post('file1.php', {req : "long process"}, function (data) {
           //do some stuff
        });
}
function post2(){
    $.post('file2.php', {req : "short process"}, function (data) {
           //do some stuff
        });
}
```

Now assume I clicked button1 and it sent post request to file1. When I clicked button2 before post1 return,  it waits to finish post1 finish then send its request. Since button1 request takes some time, I want to send post2 request without wait post1 end.

How can I do that?

Comment: Any reason not to use `$.ajax` ??

Comment: Are you sure the second function is waiting for the first one to complete? Ajax requests are asynchronous, so that shouldn't happen. Maybe it's the server you are posting to that is waiting for requests to complete?

Comment: @dianuj, what is wrong with `$.post` ?

Comment: that is what `post` suppose to do..please check you console..send request asynchoronusly...

Comment: @NADH Is there any thing that I can do on server side?

Comment: `$.post` is simply a shorthand for `$.ajax({type: 'POST'})`, so there's no issue in using it. `$.ajax` is also [asynchronous by default](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score -2):

Use a variable to store the state of the first post request.

```
var post1State = "not_sent";
var post2State = "not_sent";

function post1() {
    post1State = "pending_response";
    $.post('file1.php', {whatever}, function(data) {
        post1State = "received";

        /* Check if the second request has been
           queued; if yes, then send it off */
        if ("queued" == post2State) {
            triggerPost2();
        }
    });
}

function post2() {
    /* Don't send the second post if the first
       request is not complete; Also flag the
       second request as pending for later */
    if ("received" != post1State) {
        post2State = "queued";

        return;
    }

    triggerPost2();
}

function triggerPost2() {
    post2State = "pending_response"; // Mark second request as pending response

    $.post(whatever for post 2...);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how this code get rid of me to wait first post finish?

Comment: I edited to add comments and fixed a bug in the code. Basically, when the second post is triggered on click, you first check if the first one has completed. If so, you set up the second one in queue. When the first completes, you check if the second has been queued. If yes, then you execute the second request.

Comment: this is not I want. I need to send each posts simultaneously and get their retuns.

Comment: In that case, just remove the condition check from `post2()`.